# Don't see object values from ASP.NET Core MVC in Angular 7 http get

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I developed an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API service and try to use `HttpGet`
method:  http://localhost:50223/api/ArtistsLibrary/ListArtists

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("ListArtists")]
public JsonResult ListArtists()
{
    var artists = _context.Artists.ToList();
    return Json(new { results = artists });
}

public class Artist
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public FakeData fake { get; set; }
}

public class FakeData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
}
```

It returns:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fake": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "m1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "fake": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "m2"
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

Everything is OK, but when I try to get the data from Angular 7, I got "fake = null":

```
getArtistsList(): Observable<Artist[]> {
    return this.http.get<Artist[]>(this.myAppUrl + 
          'api/ArtistsLibrary/ListArtists');   }

  LoadData() {
    this._artistsService.getArtistsList().subscribe((d) => {
      debugger;
      this.artists = d;
      console.log(this.artists);
    });
}
```

Results:

```
Array(2) 0: fake: null id: 1
```

1: fake: null id: 2

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What does your Artist interface look like in your Angular app?

Comment: Did you test http://localhost:50223/api/ArtistsLibrary/ListArtists on Postman or your browser to make sure it gives the expected results?

Comment: Yes,I checked on Postman and gave expected results.
Problem only in get of Angular 7 with object FakeData.

Comment: The same problem if I add to Artist class member public List<Song> all_songs { get; set; }.Then I get in http service  in Angular all_songs = null (http get).

Comment: export class ArtistsService {
  myAppUrl = 'http://localhost:50223/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArtistsList(): Observable<Artist[]> {
    return this.http.get<Artist[]>(this.myAppUrl + 'api/ArtistsLibrary/ListArtists');
  }
}

Comment: Share us defination for `Artist` in angular.

Comment: export class Artist {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    date_of_birth: Date;
    all_songs: Song[];
    greatest_hits: Song[];
    image_url: string;
    band_members: BandMember[];
    genres: Genres[];
}

export class Song {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    lyrics: string;
    date_released: Date;
}

export class BandMember {
    id: number;
    member: string;
}

Comment: My question in general form is how can I pass object from WEB API CORE 2.0 to Angular 7.
Please give me example.

Comment: What is the defination for `this.artists`? Here is a working demo [CoreAngular](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/CoreAngular/ClientApp/src/app/fetch-data/fetch-data.component.ts#L97)

Comment: artists: Artist[];

Comment: Tao Zhou - your code is the same as my code