# How can I pass object from WEB API CORE 2.0 to Angular 7?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I pass object from WEB API CORE 2.0 to Angular 7?
Please give me example.
I got object = null in Angular 7 and don't understand why.

**Web Api Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("ListArtists")]
public JsonResult ListArtists()
{
    var artists = _context.Artists.ToList();
    return Json(new { results = artists });
}
```

**POCO Classes**

```
public class Artist
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public FakeData fake { get; set; }
}
public class FakeData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**Angular models**

```
export class Artist {
  id: number;
  fake: FakeData;
}
export class FakeData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**Getting data in angular using observable**

```
getArtistsList(): Observable<Artist[]> { 
  return this.http.get<Artist[]>(this.myAppUrl + 'api/ArtistsLibrary/ListArtists'); 
}
```

**component**

```
artists_count: number;
  artists: Artist[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({ searchText: [null, null] });
    this.LoadData();
  }
  LoadData() {
    console.log("LoadData");
    console.log("checkedList=" + this.checkedList);
    const genre_storage = sessionStorage.getItem("genre");
    debugger;
    this._artistsService
      .getArtistsList()
      .pipe()
      .subscribe((artists: Artist[]) => {
        this.artists = artists;
        this.artists_count = artists.length;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Pls add relevant code here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't see object values from ASP.NET Core MVC in Angular 7 http get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962597/dont-see-object-values-from-asp-net-core-mvc-in-angular-7-http-get)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a method in webapi controller to pass the object after serializing into json format. 
In angular, you can call that route using angular service to get that json. The json can be mapped into your required javascript object in angular.

This way you are able to pass C# object from asp.net core into javascript object in angular.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("ListArtists")]
public IActionResult ListArtists()
{
    var artists = _context.Artists.ToList();
    return Ok(artists);
}
```

Try checking if the url endpoint is giving you json data. It is a parsing problem.

Comment: That's what I did(I attached my code).
But got object = null in Angular 7.

Comment: I have changed my answer. Try calling the url from browser or postman. If it gives the data check the format it is giving. Since you are putting array of `Artist`,your json result should be enclosed with `[]`.

Comment: I tried. IActionResult and JsonResult both correct and I have no problem with webapi.

Comment: Postman is correct for both IActionresult snd Jsonresult. Problem that Angular returns object Fakedata = null.

Comment: How u subscribed?

Comment: artists_count: number;
  artists: Artist[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'searchText': [null, null],
    });

    this.LoadData();
  }

  LoadData() {
    console.log('LoadData');
    console.log('checkedList=' + this.checkedList);
    const genre_storage = sessionStorage.getItem('genre');
    debugger;

    this._artistsService.getArtistsList().pipe()
      .subscribe((artists: Artist[]) => {
        this.artists = artists;
        this.artists_count = artists.length;
      });
  }

Comment: try to remove `pipe()`. since you are not doing anything using pipe.

Comment: without pipe -  the same problem